# Using two collection in MongoDB with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm new to NodeJS, and I'm using the following:
Express
Mongoose
passport

HI I have two collections in MongoDB, they both have nothing to do with each other, they're called:

```
Post
```

and

```
User
```

In a get route for `/home` in an IF statement I am trying to query information from both collections and render them in an EJS page. My initial thoughts were create find for one model store in a var, then use it in another function when rendering the page.

Here is the relevant code:

```
app.get("/home", function(req, res){
  console.log(req.user._id);
  if (req.isAuthenticated()){
    // //*Find current logged in user details
    User.find({_id: req.user._id}, function(err, users){
      var currentUserName = req.user.name
      });

    //*end
    Post.find({}, function(err, posts){
      res.render("home", {
        startingContent: homeStartingContent,
        posts: posts,
        currentUser: currentUserName
        });
    });

  } else {
    res.redirect("login")
  }
});
```

At the start of my js file, i have declared

```
var currentUserName
```

But its not displaying the value in the home.ejs for:

```
<p><%= currentUser %></p>
```

Its just blank.

What am I doing wrong here? I thought using var would make it a global variable and then can be used in another function? Other posts have suggested a aggregate, but these collections are completely seperate and have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: Is your issue solved?

Answer (score 0):

It won't work, because every variable has scope. Scope means access to use that var. In this case `currentUserName` has scope or can be used only in `User.find()` section. If you want to use it in Post.find(), then do it by declaring it in main function as below.

```
app.get("/home", function(req, res){
  console.log(req.user._id);
  let currentUserName;
  if (req.isAuthenticated()){
    User.find({_id: req.user._id}, function(err, users){
      currentUserName = req.user.name
      });

    Post.find({}, function(err, posts){
      res.render("home", {
        startingContent: homeStartingContent,
        posts: posts,
        currentUser: currentUserName
        });
    });

  } else {
    res.redirect("login")
  }
});
```

It will work as you require by declaring `currentUserName` in main function, so it will be used in whole main `app.get()` function

Comment: Better to use `let` than `var`

Comment: Yes `let` is better then `var` in scope expressions. Thank you for suggestions @AymanArif

Answer (score 0):

You have defined `currentUserName` inside `User.find(){...}` function and it is accessible only within that function. You need to define the variable that can be block-scoped, outside `User.find(){...}` function. Check the code snippet below:

```
app.get("/home", function(req, res){
  console.log(req.user._id);
  if (req.isAuthenticated()){
    let currentUserName;
    // //*Find current logged in user details
    User.find({_id: req.user._id}, function(err, users){
      currentUserName = req.user.name
      });

    //*end
    Post.find({}, function(err, posts){
      res.render("home", {
        startingContent: homeStartingContent,
        posts: posts,
        currentUser: currentUserName
        });
    });

  } else {
    res.redirect("login")
  }
});
```

Javascript best practices tells that it is better to use `let` instead of `var`. Variables declared by `var` keyword are scoped to the immediate function body i.e. `User.find(){...}` while let variables are scoped to the immediate enclosing block denoted by { }, i.e. `if(req.isAuthenticated()){...}`.